# Laravel 8 multi auth using jetstream fortify?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

what is the solution for multi Auth in Laravel 8 using jetstream and fority and i don't want to use PHP artisan make:auth command.

Comment: You dont need that command, because  `php artisan make:auth` is for  `laravel/ui`, which has removed from Laravel 8.x.

Comment: thanx for reply but my main problem is how to use multi auth using jet-stream and fortify

Answer (score 1):

You have to create multiple Guard linked with multiple table;
Default Guard is linked to user table so if you want to make admin you have to create admin guard linked to admin table!